# Call function from another function and move on (don't wait for finish) python

Tags: python, function, background, multiprocessing

I read a lot of about multiprocessing, threading but still i have problem with simple thing. I have 2 functions. I want call one by another and move one (this called function can't slow me up).

Example

```
def main():
    print("my operations")
    Thread(target=child(), args=()).start()
    print("rest operations")


def child():
    #here are some operations that takes 3 seconds
    print("background operations")
```

The point is that operations from child function can not slow me down. I want to just call that function and move on. So I want output like that:

> ```
> my operations
> rest operations
> background operations
> ```

But doing this using `Thread(target=child(), args=()).start()` looks like

> ```
> my operations
> ```

```
#then call child function wait 3 seconds
```

> ```
> background operations
> rest operations
> ```

There is and option to do what I want ?

Comment: `sleep` stops THE ENTIRE PROGRAM not just the thread it was called on. as an alternative you can use async programming

Comment: this sleep is just for showing the problem I will edit it. @Nullman look now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do

```
Thread(target=child(), args=()).start()
```

you are calling child on the main thread, and then passing the result as the target! You want to pass the `child` function itself, not the result of calling it:

```
Thread(target=child, args=()).start()
```

Comment: so how should I do that ?

Comment: Lite i showed you; `target=child`, not `target=child()`.

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed difference.

Answer (score 1):

python threads are not concurrent, at least not in CPython, because of the GIL(Global Interperter Lock). Threads will run one at a time and will switch between themselves according to several rules, like waiting for IO (like a web request for instance) or if the thread has been running for too long (15ms iirc).
You don't really have a good way to force a thread switch so its not as simple to demonstrate race conditions the way you are trying to do it. [Here](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil) is a nice blog post talking about it with some examples